# How to create Numbered List without Hanging Indent in MS word

Tags: microsoft-word

Generally when we create a Numbered List in MS Word, it creates Left Indent with Hanging Indent by default (Please see the "Numbered List Type-A in the below image):
[image]

Now I want to create a "Numbered List Type-B" in which there will not be any Left Indent along with no hanging indent. Although I can simulate this type of numbered list by selecting all the paragraphs after creating the Numbered List Type-A, and then set the Left Indent to 0 and Special Indent to (None) from Paragraph settings. But this does not let me readjust the Number and Text position by the "Adjust List Indents" option. So, I think my way is not the right way.

Any one have an idea how to create the "Numbered List Type-B" in a proper way so that I can readjust the Numbered List after that?

Comment: Cross-posted at https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-create-numbered-list-without-hanging-indent/4f5b4c5d-9a35-41e2-a3c8-3e3c7e4630e2 --- For cross-posting etiquette, please read: A Message to Forum Cross-Posters https://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Comment: @Charles Kenyon, as from my previous experience I found that there need some time for getting answer in forum for a problem and this is little bit urgently needed in my case. So I have posted it to other forums so that I can get a quick solution. I have noticed your response there as well and would like to give you thanks for that. Still waiting for a alternative way. As soon as I will get an easier solution from either forums, I will delete my question from all other forums. Hope you will understand. Thanks

Comment: Please, please, please, read A Message to Forum Cross-Posters  https://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Comment: How to Post and When to Cross-Post
Admittedly, some posts do go without answers, and this is where the cross post can be beneficial. Just do it in the right way! My suggestion, for what it's worth, is to follow this series of events:

Comment: Find one forum and stick with it, preferably a very busy one so you reach a bigger audience. If you don't get a satisfactory answer in a reasonable amount of time (days, not hours), then:
Post in another applicable forum with your issue (1 or 2 other forums, not 20!).
Include a link to your original post (see below).
Make it very obvious that you have not got an answer to your question and are looking for more experts.
Ask people to post their replies in the original forum.
When it is solved, go back and mark it as such in all forums so that we're not chasing solved issues.

Comment: So, I have a scope to post it to other forums. All I did not do, included a link to the original post, which I am going to do right now for the other forum as the Superuser was the original forum.

Comment: Thank you. It is important. The idea is even if you ask in multiple forums, all eventually link to the answer. This makes the forums more useful for others searching them.

Answer (score 0):

My preference for any numbering in Word is to follow the advice in Shauna Kelly's [Creating Outline or Heading Numbering in Microsoft Word](http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html).

You use the Define New MultiLevel List dialog and attach each level you will be using to an existing paragraph style. You can adjust the indents for each of these levels in that dialog. Although she uses the heading styles for this, you can use any paragraph style including custom styles. Do not use the Normal style. Once this is set up, to tell Word to number a paragraph, use the style, not the buttons on the ribbon.

Since your numbering level is attached to a style, you can [assign a keyboard shortcut to the style](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm#Keyboard). The built-in keyboard shortcut for the Normal style (to return to unnumbered) is `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`N`.

Comment: Thank you but I would like to wait for other's answers as well whether there is an alternative way to modify the current Numbered List to serve my purpose or not. If not I will follow your advice and will accept your answer.

But thanks for your prompt answer.

Regards

Comment: The only way to control indents in numbering lists is through the Define New MultiLevel List dialog. Here is my page on Numbering in Microsoft Word. http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/numbering.htm

Comment: Thankyou.... I don't want to tell it "Only way" because you can see in my question that I can simulate that style using the Numbered List (Number List Type-2) as well. But the problem is, later I can't readjust the spacing in between Number and Text for all paragraphs combinedly. But I can adjust them separately for each paragraph. So, I hope there might be some tweaks, but not sure, waiting for other's response.

Comment: In earlier versions of Word, it was possible to access a dialog to customize flat lists and adjust alignment and indents without resorting to the multilevel list dialog. Now, the simplest way is to use the multi-level list dialog, even if for only one level. This is discussed briefly in my chapter on numbering. http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/numbering.htm#Customizing

Comment: It might be possible to still access that legacy dialog, but it is not enumerated in documentation of dialogs: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdworddialog